# DJANGO: NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_comment.lesson_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I try create **comments form** add and take error. But I'm not shure that I correctly use  *lesson =* at view.py at *def post* function.
Can You help me?

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
text = models.TextField('Comment text')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

view.py:

```
class LessonDetailPage(DetailView):
....
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        lesson = Lesson.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['lesson_slug']).first()
    
        post = request.POST.copy()
        post['user'] = request.user
        post['lesson'] = lesson
        request.POST = post
    
        form = CommentForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
```

part of urls.py

```
path('course/<slug>/<lesson_slug>', views.LessonDetailPage.as_view(), name='lesson-detail'),
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentForms(forms.ModelForm):

text = forms.CharField(
    label='Text',
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)
user = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.HiddenInput()
)
lesson = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.HiddenInput()
)

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']
```

comment.html

```
<div class="form-section">
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">ОК</button>
</div>
```

And my Error

```
IntegrityError at /course/linux/set-on-linux
NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_comment.lesson_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/linux/set-on-linux
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: courses_comment.lesson_id
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that this is causing your issue:

```py
lesson = Lesson.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['lesson_slug']).first()
```

What this is doing is returning the first Lesson object in a queryset filtered by your lesson slug. However, filter will return an empty queryset if there are no results. Running `first()` on that empty queryset will return nothing, which would explain why an ID is not being passed to your form.

To solve this, you just need to catch whether the `lesson` object is empty:

```py
if lesson is None:
   # do something else
```

As an aside, combining `.filter()` and `.first()` is generally not recommended as you are potentially being vague with your object selection. Using `.get()` will get you a single object and return an error if two or more are returned. The downside with `.get()` is that it will also raise an exception if nothing is returned, so you need to handle both outcomes in your view.

Comment: I try take name of lesson "/set-on-linux" from URL...
http://127.0.0.1:8000/course/linux/set-on-linux

Comment: But does `set-on-linux` exist as a Lesson in your database?

Comment: ok I 100% get it
course = Lesson.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['lesson_slug']).first()
lesson = course.slug
print(lesson)

terminal show: set-on-linux

but Error

Comment: print(form) show:
<textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control" required id="id_text">
sdvsdvsdvs</textarea><input type="hidden" name="user" value="admin" id="id_user"><input type="hidden" name="lesson" value="set-on-linux" id="id_lesson">

Answer (score 0):

But better at forms.py write:

```
class CommentForms(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text', 'user', 'lesson'] #here is the answer
    widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput(), 'lesson': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

then at views.py:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    course = Course.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug']).first()
    lesson = Lesson.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['lesson_slug']).first()
    post = request.POST.copy()
    post['user'] = request.user
    post['lesson'] = lesson
    request.POST = post

    form = CommentForms(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

May be not best solution but It's work:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lesson = Lesson.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['lesson_slug']).first()
        post = request.POST.copy()
        post['user'] = request.user
        post['lesson'] = lesson
        request.POST = post
    
        form = CommentForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            comment = Comment(text=request.POST['text'], user=request.POST['user'], lesson=request.POST['lesson'])
            comment.save()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).